# Printing number with decimal point

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion

Well I am having trouble to print numbers with decimal point.
When I run python and ask it to do a division, in which the result must be a number with decimal point, it doesn't print the decimal point.
For instance, I have just made this algorithm:

```
print 'Report card calculation'
grade1 = input ('Insert the first grade: ')
grade2 = input ('Insert the second grade: ')
grade3 = input ('Insrt the third grade: ')

media = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3
print 'Your final result is', media
```

But when it prints the "media", the number which should have a decimal point doesn't come with a decimal point. How can I fix it?

Comment: what are your inputs? are they integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest change: divide by `3.0` instead of `3`:

```
media = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3.0
```

This will ensure that the value assigned to `media` will be floating point even if the three grade variables hold ints.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your file, add:

```
from __future__ import division
```

or use 3.0 instead of 3.  In Python 2, dividing two integers always produces an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Your operation is handled as an integer division, try using 3.0 in place of 3, see what happens then.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide two integers in Python 2.x, the result will be an integer.  From the documentation on [Numeric Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

> For (plain or long) integer division, the result is an integer. The result is always rounded towards minus infinity: 1/2 is 0, (-1)/2 is -1, 1/(-2) is -1, and (-1)/(-2) is 0. Note that the result is a long integer if either operand is a long integer, regardless of the numeric value.

To get the behavior you want, either add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your module to use the [Python 3 division behavior](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), or change one the numerator or denominator (or both) to a float:

```
# either of the following would work
media = float(grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3
media = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3.0
```